# Why is my Vue/Vuex subscriber not firing?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, subscribe, buefy

I have set up my Vuex subscribe function to store user auth in localStorage and I can't figure out for the life of me why the subscriber isn't firing at all. I can't even get a `console.log()` from it. Here is the relevant content from my project.

**main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Buefy from 'buefy';
import axios from 'axios';
import router from '@/router';
import store from '@/store';
import App from './App.vue';
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css';
import '@/store/subscriber';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(Buefy);

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
const token = localStorage.getItem('x-auth-token');
if (token) Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = token;
Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5000/v1/';

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

**store/index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import auth from './auth';
import transactions from './transactions';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth,
    transactions,
  },
});
```

**store/subscriber.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import store from '@/store';

store.subscribe = (mutation) => {
  console.log(mutation);
  console.log("WHY AREN'T YOU WORKING!!!???");

  switch (mutation.type) {
    case 'auth/SET_TOKEN':
      if (mutation.payload) {
        Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = mutation.payload;
        localStorage.setItem('x-auth-token', mutation.payload);
      } else {
        Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = '';
        localStorage.removeItem('x-auth-token');
      }
      break;
    case 'auth/SET_USER':
      if (mutation.payload) {
        Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common.user = JSON.stringify(mutation.payload);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(mutation.payload));
      } else {
        Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common.user = '';
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
      }
      break;
    default:
      Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = '';
      Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common.user = '';
  }
};
```

**store/auth.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('x-auth-token') || '',
    user: {},
  },
  getters: {
    authenticated(state) {
      return state.token && state.user;
    },
    user(state) {
      return state.user;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_TOKEN(state, token) {
      state.token = token;
    },
    SET_USER(state, data) {
      state.user = data;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async signIn({ commit, dispatch }, credentials) {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post('users/login', credentials);
        const { token, user } = data;
        if (token) {
          commit('SET_TOKEN', token);
        }
        commit('SET_USER', user);
        return data;
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch('signOut');
        return err.response;
      }
    },
    async registerUser({ commit, dispatch }, credentials) {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post('users/register', credentials);
        const { token, user } = data;
        if (token) {
          commit('SET_TOKEN', token);
        }
        commit('SET_USER', user);

        return data;
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch('signOut');
        return err.response;
      }
    },
    signOut({ commit }) {
      commit('SET_TOKEN', '');
      commit('SET_USER', {});
    },
  },
};
```

**views/LogIn.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="title has-text-centered is-size-1 mt-6">Log In</h1>
    <div class="box column is-half is-offset-one-quarter mt-6 px-6">
      <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit" action="GET" class="my-5">
        <b-field label="Username" for="username" :type="usernameValidation">
          <b-input v-model="user.username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"></b-input>
        </b-field>
        <b-field
          label="Password"
          for="password"
          :type="passwordValidation"
          :message="passwordMessage"
        >
          <b-input
            v-model="user.password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            password-reveal
          ></b-input>
        </b-field>
        <div class="buttons is-centered">
          <b-button native-type="submit" class="is-success mt-5 mb-4 has-text-weight-bold">Log In</b-button>
        </div>
        <div class="level">
          <div class="level-left">
            <router-link class="level-item" to="/signup">Sign Up</router-link>
          </div>
          <div class="level-right">
            <router-link class="level-item" to="/forgotpassword">Forgot Password</router-link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'LogIn',
  data: () => ({
    user: {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    },
    usernameValidation: '',
    passwordValidation: '',
    passwordMessage: '',
  }),
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      signIn: 'auth/signIn',
    }),
    async handleSubmit() {
      const { data } = await this.signIn(this.user);
      if (data) {
        this.usernameValidation = 'is-danger';
        this.passwordValidation = 'is-danger';
        this.passwordMessage = data.message;
      } else {
        this.$router.push('/');
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to `import "@/store/subscriber.js"`

Comment: Thanks [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil). I added it into to my **main.js**, but still having the same issue.

Comment: Edited! [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil)

Comment: Have you restarted your dev-server? Sometimes changes in `main.js` don't apply cleanly through hot-reload. FYI, to tag someone in a comment, prefix their name with an `@` symbol, eg `@AlexDodd`

Comment: Thanks @Phil. Wasn't sure if that tagging was working. I have restarted my servers, front and back. Still not working.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're committing any mutations? Everything looks ok as far as I can see. You would just need to make sure you're doing something to trigger them (such as submitting your form)

Comment: Yeah, the form submits, the page redirects, and the mutations are being committed, and I can see that state is being updated in the Vue Dev tools. That's why I'm so baffled by why the subscriber isn't being called, because it seems as though everything else in the cycle is working as expected.

Comment: I'm just using the standard Vue cli to run it locally at http://localhost:8080/

Comment: I changed the `package.json` script to `"dev": "vue-cli-service serve",` so I am just using `dev` instead of `serve`

Answer (score 2):

You are totally going to kick yourself.

Two problems

1. You weren't including the `subscribe.js` file so your subscriber was never being subscribed. You've since imported this in `main.js` which solves that issue.
2. [`store.subscribe()`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe) is a function you are meant to call, providing a subscriber function but you are assigning it a new function. Try this instead

```js
store.subscribe((mutation) => {
  console.log(mutation);
  console.log("OMG YOU'RE WORKING!!!");

  // etc
})
```

[image: Edit goofy-architecture-pknzm]

Comment: Wow @Phil. You are the hero this world needs, but not the one it deserves. Thank you.